# Need help in rebasing

Tags: git, git-rebase

The following is a small illustration.

```
UP:1-2-4-5-6-7-..........99                    
B:    \3-----------------\
```

I made a branch after 2 and did a commit.
I tried to merge UP into B but ran into conflict, I resolved it and committed.
Now I have two commits. 
But I want to have only one. When I try to re-base, it says many conflicts on the way(the reason I put 99). Is there any way to get around this.
I just want a single commit after this.

Comment: I'm *really* not sure you want to rebase on this one.  What is the intended point, exactly?  Do you want there to be a linear progression of history?

Comment: Yes, I want a linear progression. Isn't there any way.

Comment: Basically, you want commit 3 to appear after commit 99 in branch UP, if I'm not mistaken?  Or do you want it the other way around?

Comment: If you want a quick way to create an illustration of your git history try `git log --pretty=format:"%h" --graph --decorate`.

Comment: You can try to go to UP branch, then cherry-pick the `3` commit in the B branch. In this case you must resolve conflicts only once. Then you can delete B branch because its commit is ported into UP.

Comment: Some general advice: Try to get the idea of linear history out of your head. Linear history is a lie, most of the time. And such lies have negative consequences. Unless you have very good reason to rebase, don't do it. Merge instead the way you did.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand, you want to put `3` commit from B branch on the top of UP branch (just after `99`).

If you try to rebase B over UP, you should resolve conflicts for every UP commit. This can be tedious. you can tell git to use conflict resolution from previous commit anyway.

But considering that we're talking of only one commit, the best way that I see is to checkout the `UP` branch and then cherry-pick the `3` commit. This copy the differences of `3` commit directly over the UP branch. You must resolve conflicts (if any) only once. Then, if it works, you can delete the B branch.

Answer (score 1):

checkout up and do

`git diff UP B | git apply`

then commit the result with the same message than 3

If you want the 'all-in-one' command, should be:

```
git diff UP B| git apply  && git add -u && git commit -m "$(git log -1 --pretty=%B your-sha1-for-commit-3)"
```